# In how many days can they do all the work together?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$A$ and $B$ can do a work in $10$ days. $B$ and $C$ in $15$ days. $C$ and $A$ in $30$ days. In how many days can they do it all working together?

Comment: If I understood the problem well, what you should do is solve $A + B = 10, B + C = 15, A + C=30$ which is a system of three equations and three unknowns.

Comment: please you do this for me

Comment: @BolzWeir, your proposed solution is incorrect. That would imply that A+B+C=33.5, which is incorrect, since all three working together should take the least amount of time.

Comment: @MichaelDyrud To me the problem seems ill-posed, we don't know the relationship between the objects and the times given. Maybe BolzWeir is correct; $A$, $B$ and $C$ are 3 people who don't get along and forcing them to work together reduces productivity.

Comment: Stephen Leacock  http://www.online-literature.com/stephen-leacock/literary-lapses/40/  seems relevant...

Comment: acha yaar rola nahh pao

Comment: Try reading up on the difference between $Frequency$ and $Period$.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume each person does the same amount of work per day, and that when they work together their rates add together, then the solution is as follows.

$A$ and $B$ do $1/10$ of a "work" in one day.

$B$ and $C$ do $1/15$ of a "work" in one day.

$A$ and $C$ do $1/30$ of a "work" in one day.

\begin{align}
A+B&=1/10\\
B+C&=1/15\\
A+C&=1/30\\
&\implies A=1/30,B=1/15, C=0
\end{align}

Since $C$ does no work(?), it still takes $10$ days if all three work together.

Comment: Shouldn't one use different symbols for names and for rates?

Answer (score 0):

Let a, b, and c be the fractions of "a work" that A, B, and C individually can do in one day.

Then $$10a + 10 b = 1$$
$$15b + 15c=1$$ $$30a+30c =1$$
Solve for a, b, and c;  the number of days working together is:
$$N = \frac{1}{a+b+c}$$